# Match values stored in local macros with those in a variable

Tags: loops, stata, stata-macros

In my data, I have a string variable `ICD9CODX` like the one below:

```
|ICD9CODX|
|:-------|
|410     |
|411     |
|398     |
|196     |
```

I would like to search/match each observation within some code sets defined as Stata local macros. So if the code belongs to a set, a variable that flags the existence of codes for that set is created and set to value `1`, and `0` otherwise.

Examples of my local macros are the following:

```
local cond_1 410 411
local cond_2 398 402 428
...
local cond_17 196 197 198 199
```

Expected result:

```
|ICD9CODX|condition_1|condition_2|........|condition_17|
|:-------|----------:|----------:|--------|-----------:|
|410     |          1|          0|........|           0|
|411     |          1|          0|........|           0|        
|398     |          0|          1|........|           0|
|196     |          0|          0|........|           1|
```

I tried using the loops below but `0` real changes were made:

```
forvalues i = 1/17 {
    generate condition_`i' = 0
    foreach dx in cond_`i' {
        replace condition_`i' = 1 if strtrim(ICD9CODX) == "`dx'"
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my loops?

Answer (score 0):

Trace your loops. Set `i` to 1 and then

```
 cond_`i'
```

becames

```
 cond_1
```

and your `replace` command compares your variable with that as a literal string. That's legal but nothing will happen if that is not a (trimmed) value of your variable. The same is true for the other 16 cases, `cond_2` to `cond_17`.

What you should have written is quite different:

```
forvalues i = 1/17 {
    generate condition_`i' = 0
    foreach dx of local cond_`i' {
        replace condition_`i' = 1 if strtrim(ICD9CODX) == "`dx'"
    }
}
```